# How to make a "Select All" function for one page only

Tags: javascript, checkbox, pagination, selectall

Let's say I have a page with 100 checkboxes. I used this pagination Javascript  (http://en.newinstance.it/2006/09/27/client-side-html-table-pagination-with-javascript/) to break them into small pages (each with around 10 checkboxes) within the same page.

I have already created a "select all" function for all 100 checkboxes. The thing is I want to create a "Select All" function for just the 10 checkboxes that are visible on the page on top of that. Not sure if anyone knows how to do it...

Comment: Probably you can keep a count to select the specified 10 check boxes alone

Comment: Hey buddy. did any of the answers solve your issue? if so, it's good practice to tick it. This helps future visitors and is good for the answerer.

Answer (score 0):

You can give the groups a class each. Then you can use:

```
var checkBoxArray = document.getElementsByClass('<your class>');
```

Then you can cycle through the items in this array and execute something like this:

```
checkBoxArray[i].checked=true;
```

Unless I'm mistaken about what you mean, *something like* that should do.

Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

The pagination library hides other rows by setting `display:none` to them, so you just check if a row is visible, just check the checkbox.

Answer (score 0):

i trust them for be in the same div, if so create a checkbox and use the following jQuery code:

```
$("#urMasterCheckbox").click(function(){
    $('input:checkbox').prop('checked', $("#urMasterCheckbox").is('checked');
}
```

this will ensure that when clicking on the so called master checkbox all on the next checkboxs will will be check according to his check status.
learn more about using jQuery, it really makes your code be more fast,light and  efficient.
here is a link: [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) , download it or ref it in your code.
good luck